# What occasion should use the word "affection"

Tags: single-word-requests

Hi this is my first post !! Salute to y'all nice people!!

I am not a native English speaker so sometimes I concerned about if I picked up the correct word.

The word today is "affection". I try to describe a guy holds a little boy and like it as much as his own son, so I use `He shows him(the boy) much affection like to his own son.`

I am not sure that's the correct phrase, the reason I use this word is the guy is not the real father to the kid so `love` sounds too much and `like` sounds dull. But I am not sure if `affection` make the guys sounds perverted, from a man to a kid. Because nowadays people need to be careful to show fondness to kids...and my native language does not has a equivalence as this word, we generally use "like" all the time :)

Also I am always confused about this word, it sounds like a little more than like but less than love but with some "love". So what is the normal occasion to use this word? Only to kids? a thing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to use a qualifier such as "fatherly affection".

Comment: @Kristina Lopez ie 'He had an affection for him' sounds rather strange whilst 'He had a fatherly affection for him' sounds totally acceptable. To someone who's used the language regularly for tens of years.

Answer (score 5):

*Affection* is an acceptable word to use in the context you describe. Other words would be *fondness*, *tenderness*, or *warmth*, as in:

- His fondness for the boy was like that of a father towards his son.
- He felt tenderness toward the boy, as if he were one of his own
  children.
- His warmth toward the boy was like a father's.
- He affectionately held the boy as if holding his own
  child.

I think including the phrases *like a father*, etc. save the description from seeming to indicate an improper relationship.